# Multiple Producers writing to same SQS. How to avoid starvation? And what are the throttling limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a use case where multiple producers write (tps is around 10k for each producer) to same SQS (Standard). What happens when 2 or more producers write at the same time, how does the message order be affected in that case? what exactly is the limit at which the system breaks (i see max inflight messages can be 120,000) ?

Comment: The infligt messages have nothing to do with producers, but consumers. What starvation are you talking about? How many messages are there? Do you actually expect to exceed 120k inflight messages, how? SQS does not have any order in message processing so no particular producer should be at a disadvantage.

Comment: *"how does the message order be affected"* - there is no order to be affected, messages are unordered even for a single producer & single consumer. *"Standard queues support a nearly unlimited number of API calls per second, per API action"* - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html

Comment: so there is an equal chance for every message to be processed. And on consumer side, do we need to maintain multiple threads and use receive message (upto 10 requests) in order to meet the high tps from producers?

Comment: Not sure about any probabilities, you cannot rely on any ordering. How many threads you need really depends on the way the consumer is built, how many parallel consumers are there in the first place, how fast do they process the messages, how fast is their network communication to SQS, ... This is too broad to answer.

Comment: Does "tps" mean transactions (ie, messages) per second? If yes, do you realize that you'll be paying approximately $1,000 per day just for queue operations? Plus whatever you will be paying for consumers (and to keep up, given the SQS limit of 10 messages per request, you'll need lots of consumers)

Comment: I suspect that the point at which the system breaks will be that your consumers can't keep up with your producers, and you have an ever-increasing number of messages in queue (note: those are _not_ in-flight messages), which will eventually be deleted when they pass the retention period (max 14 days). What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?